How to initialize SwiftUI Map Camera on user's location?
I am trying to initialize my MapKit Map in SwiftUI using the User's Location I obtained from Core Location, currently I initialize my Map with a MapCameraPosition type Variable, how can I start the map using CoreLocation.
This my current map initialization pretty much
    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .region(
        MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: .monterrey,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001)
        )
    )
    @State private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    private var mapLayer: some View {
            Map(position: $position) {
                ForEach(vm.filteredMarkers) { marker in
                    Annotation(marker.name, coordinate: marker.coordinate) {
                        RecyclingMarker {
                            selectMarker(marker)
                        }
                    }
                }
                if let userLocation = locationManager.currentLocation {
                    Annotation("Your Location", coordinate: userLocation) {
                        Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .mapStyle(.standard)
        }

I am trying to extract the coordinates from Core Location into a MapCameraPosition but I haven't been able to do this.

you could try adding a .onAppear{...} to your View or Map and using .camera, for example:
.onAppear {
    if let userLocation = locationManager.currentLocation {
        position = .camera(MapCamera(centerCoordinate: userLocation, distance: 400000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0))
    }
}

And/or
.onChange(of: locationManager.currentLocation) {
    if let userLocation = locationManager.currentLocation {
        position = .camera(MapCamera(centerCoordinate: userLocation, distance: 400000.0, heading: 0, pitch: 0))
    }
}

Adjust the distance and other parameters to suit your needs.

did my answer not worked for you?
